# Anyone having issues installing bson_ext gem in OSX lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, mongoid

OSX Lion, Xcode 4.2, GCC 4.2

I get the following error installing bson_ext 1.4.1

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bson_ext:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for asprintf()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Comment: Do you have developer tools installed?

Comment: Same issue here. 1.4.0 worked without any problems.

Comment: Yup I have Xcode 4.2 installed recently. Is there a separate package for developer tools?

Comment: FWIW I ran into this on my iMac where I had an older version of Xcode. When I switched to my MacBook Air with the latest Xcode (4.2) my bundle install went off without a hitch. Interesting.

Comment: Kind of makes sense.  I had Xcode 4.1 installed at first, but I wanted to install Xcode 4.2 so I uninstalled it via command line.  My xcode 4.2 is working properly and it appears nothing is wrong with GCC.  Is there a check I can run to ensure my developer tools are working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this. You should look in the mkmf.log file. Chances are, it's looking for GCC in the wrong place. I had to:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1
```

And all was well.

Comment: Where the heck do I find mkmf.log? Anyway, this worked for me: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2` via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4

Comment: In the output you get "Results logged to ${GEM_HOME}/gems/bson_ext-1.8.0/ext/cbson/gem_make.out" - the mkmf.log resides in the same dir as gem_make.out.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. OS X 10.8.2, Xcode 4.6 (with command-line tools), bson_ext 1.8.2. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me. But this did.

I am using:

- OS X 10.8.2
- Xcode 4.6 (with command line tools)
- bson_ext 1.8.2

`cd /usr/bin && sudo ln -s ./gcc gcc-4.2`

```
$ gem install bson_ext -v 1.8.2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed bson_ext-1.8.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bson_ext-1.8.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for bson_ext-1.8.2...
```

Answer (score 0):

So re-installing OSX lion fixed the problem. I guess uninstalling xcode 4.1 in the first place messed up my developer tools installation.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use XCode for anything but the developer tool binaries so I just uninstalled XCode:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

And then installed this:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Fixed the problem right up and I saved some HD space to boot.