# how to install cc on mac os 10.8 without paying for developer program?

Tags: python, macos, osx-mountain-lion, cc

Several python libraries stopped working after upgrade to Mac OS 10.8. Attempt to re-install them through easy_install or pip brings error message "-bash: cc: command not found". XCode is installed. Attempt to install Command line tools for XCode insist on enrolling into developer program. I don't want to pay $99 for what used to work. I don't need to distribute anything — I'm not developing anything Apple has to do with.

Is there a way to obtain c compiler, make, and all this stuff without declaring myself a Mac developer/paying $99 a year?

UPDATE: guys, what these negative votes are about? You know the answer? You don't like to know there are problems with Mac OS X 10.8? I'm really confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4 ?

Comment: You sure it's making you pay? Developer accounts are free, enrolling in the program is $99

Comment: Gary, solution proposed in that thread is not working. Link to Command Line tools there is for 10.7 only although it's marked with July 25, 2012 date (when 10.8 is already publicly released). So the question remains.

Comment: Woody, free developer account in 10.8 does not let you download Command Line tools without enrolling into developer program, which I have no need for — I'm not a developer, I just need to make my python scripts working again. :(

Answer (score 3):

Command Line Tools are available for free:

- visit https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action
- log in with your personal Apple ID
- fill the form
- after confirmation you will be able to download tools absolutely free (or install them from Xcode).

Also check https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/
Probably it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Have you tried that after upgrade to 10.8? And were not asked for $99 enrollment charge?

Comment: Exactly. I've downloaded Command Line Tools yesterday after updating to 10.8 with my personal Apple ID without any payments.

There are to items in dev center:
- Command Line Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012 (for 10.7)
- Xcode 4.4 (you should choose this one)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install the command line tools from within Xcode by going to preferences and downloads. If it is still complaining try using xcrun to access the built in tools. xcrun lets you access the built in xcode tools from the command line.

xcrun -find cc to find where llvm is and then you could setup your environment to work around it.

Example:

```
xcrun -find cc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
lomion@basso.local:/usr/bin>xcrun cc
clang: error: no input files
Exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this will work, but it won't wreck your computer so why not. You can download the Clang toolchain here http://llvm.org/releases/download.html. You'll want the Clang Binaries for MacOS X/x86_64. It should install llvm, gcc, cc and everything for you.