# install boost_1_53_0 on mac os x mountain lion

Tags: macos, boost

I want to install boost on my freshly installed mac os x mountain lion.

I've downloaded boost_1_53_0 and followed every step of every guides I could find but I keep ending with the same error which is: `"Failed to build Boost.Build build engine"`.

It won't even build and can't even find ./b2 to install..

Is there anyone who could help me out here and tell me how to install boost without using macports?

bootstrap.log:

```
###
### Using 'darwin' toolset.
###
rm -rf bootstrap
mkdir bootstrap
cc -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathunix.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c pwd.c class.c native.c md5.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execunix.c fileunix.c
./build.sh: line 15: cc: command not found
```

Comment: Check the answers for the following questions: [how to install cc on mac os 10.8...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660573/how-to-install-cc-on-mac-os-10-8-without-paying-for-developer-program) and [How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4)

Comment: omg, you must be kidding me... wasted 6 hours because I forgot to reinstall those tools.. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Use Homebrew (or see [Homebrew's building way](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/boost.rb))

then `brew install boost`