# Why won't bundler install the json 1.7.4 gem on OS X 10.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, makefile, bundler

I'm on OS X 10.8 with XCode 4.4, Ruby 1.9.3, and Rails 3.2.

When I clone my rails project from git and run:

```
bundle install
```

I get:

Installing json (1.7.4) 
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/json-1.7.4/.gitignore
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.4'` succeeds before bundling.

Then I try:

```
gem install json -v '1.7.4'
```

and get:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /Users/scalessec/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/json-1.7.4/.gitignore

Okay. Permissions issue, right? Let's try:

```
sudo gem install json -v '1.7.4'
```

No go. Here's what I get:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: Permission denied
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

What the heck?

Comment: I just had a problem installing json 1.7.4 on Arch Linux; it was failing because the Makefile was looking for `/bin/install` when it should have been calling `/usr/bin/install`; my point is, I think there is something wrong with that release of that gem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure, but I upgraded to OS X 10.8 2 days ago (from Lion, where my Rails configuration worked fine). And I had the same JSON 1.7.4 issue.

Eventually, I solved the problem by noticing that Xcode's command line tools were NOT installed (but they were on OS X 10.7!). **I just reinstalled CLI tools in Xcode** and that JSON 1.7.4 issue disappeared.

Also just in case it's helpful, check out this guide: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer, since it will probably be the most helpful to other users. I, in fact, already had CLI tools installed so that wasn't it. I think this was specifically a compiler issue. Regardless, reinstalling ruby & rails did the trick.

Comment: This happened to me too. I opened up XCode and it prompted me to update the CLI tools.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to aabulkhairov for his solution.

Here's one for anyone having the same symptom but **still running OS X Lion**

I was able to updating Xcode to 4.4 from the App Store, then using XCode > Preferences > Downloads to **install CLI tools**; this resolved the problem.  The new XCode is compatible with Lion, and my Rails app is running as expected.

I think I got into this state because the previous version of XCode 4.2.1, installed from the App Store, had displaced my even older version downloaded from developer.apple.com -- that's likely where I lost the CLI tools.  Since that time, I apparently never needed to compile a gem with native extensions again.

Comment: Reinstalling Command Line Tool worked for me. After I launched Xcode, it prompted me to update a few things. I did this, then followed these instructions and installed CLI tools (I also had them before the upgrade to Mountain Lion). Once this completed, bundle install worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Re-install CLI tools worked for me.

Use the top answer here:
[How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4)

Answer (score 0):

For OS X use:
`sudo gem install json --pre` for the latest one

Check the version of Ruby you are using. This can be installed easily with `ruby 1.9.3`. Change the ruby version to 1.9.3 and do

`sudo gem install json -v '1.7.4'`