# matlab R2011a unable to compile mex files

Tags: matlab, gcc, mex

I have Xcode(4.4.1) installed on my mac, and use MATLAB r2011a (64 bit) on the computer. I have ben trying to compile mex files, but I get the following error:

---

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/mex: line 305: gcc-4.2: command not found
/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/mex: line 1041: gcc-4.2: command not found

    mex: compile of ' "mdwt.c"' failed.

??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in ==> compile at 39
mex mdwt.c mdwt_r.c
```

---

When I type in `"gcc"` at the command prompt (terminal) , I see that it has been installed.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to run `mex -setup` first to tell matlab which compiler is available.

Comment: thanks, i did that. Turns out there was an issue with the gcc version I had.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link:
[How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4)

For xcode 4.4, I guess you need to install gcc manually by yourself.