# Eclipse CDT can't create new projects with Standard Library

Tags: eclipse, macos, iostream, eclipse-cdt, standard-library

I'm working on a Mac and using eclipse cdt. I'm able to use and compile all the c++ projects I currently have, but when I create a new one, it doesn't recognize the standard library. It underlines `#include <iostream>` in yellow, and, if I try and compile, the errors say it can't find `iostream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [website](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html) might help you. (Section 2.1 Step 2 or just do a search on the page for iostream)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have command line tools (gcc, etc) installed? They were installed along with Xcode prior to OS X 10.8 and now you need to install them separately using Xcode UI. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4) StackOverflow question for details.