# Problems building Ada on Mac OS 10.8.2

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, ada

I have installed GNAT 4.3 from [here](http://www.macada.org/macada/Downloads.html)

And added the following to my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/ada-4.3/bin:$PATH
```

Now I can run gnatmake hello.adb

For the file hello.adb with the following contents:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Hello is
begin
    Put_Line ("Hello world!");
end Hello;
```

But I get this error:

```
gcc -c hello.adb

gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory

gnatmake: "hello.adb" compilation error
```

I'm guessing there is a problem with my GNAT installation, but I have been unable to find a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works on Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6, but I haven't tried 10.8. Two things to check:

- It looks like it can't find the assembler, `/usr/bin/as`. Verify that you installed the developer tools, as it's an optional install. See also [*How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9353444/230513).
- Use the verbose option of `gcc` to see more about where it's getting lost.

  ```
  gcc -c -v hello.adb
  ```

Comment: @SimonWright: I defer to your 10.8 experience; please don't hesitate to correct or amplify.

Comment: @trashgod: As your link suggested installing command line tools from Xcode (Xcode->Preferences->Downloads) fixed the issue.  I can now build hello.adb.