# No rubies installed with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have installed rvm on a 10.8.3 OSX system, and although it appears to have installed correctly there are no rubies installed. I run `rvm install` and nothing seems to happen.

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Certificates in '/Users/disaacs/.rvm/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
$ rvm list

rvm rubies


# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

I also tried `sudo rvm install`, but that didn't make any difference.

Any idea on what I am missing?

EDIT:
Running `rvm requirements` as suggested by Tilo has helped. But now there is a new problem

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configuring........
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-dir=/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libyaml:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/readline:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libxml2:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libxslt:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libksba:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/openssl:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/sqlite --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/disaacs/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/1367619493_configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

The contents of the specified log file are:

```
[2013-05-03 18:18:13] ./configure
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/disaacs/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

The contents of config.log are

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-dir=/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libyaml:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/readline:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libxml2:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libxslt:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libksba:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/openssl:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/sqlite --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = rabbit.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 12.3.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 8 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
8 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Primary memory available: 16.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 150 tasks, 814 threads, 8 processors
Load average: 2.92, Mach factor: 5.14
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/git/bin
PATH: /Users/disaacs/.rvm/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2792: checking build system type
configure:2806: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
configure:2874: checking host system type
configure:2887: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
configure:2907: checking target system type
configure:2920: result: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
configure:3401: checking for C compiler version
configure:3410: gcc-4.2 --version >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3421: $? = 0
configure:3410: gcc-4.2 -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /Volumes/Media/Builds/gcc-5666.3/build/obj/src/configure --disable-checking --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++,fortran --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
configure:3421: $? = 0
configure:3410: gcc-4.2 -V >&5
gcc-4.2: argument to `-V' is missing
configure:3421: $? = 1
configure:3410: gcc-4.2 -qversion >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
configure:3421: $? = 1
configure:3441: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3463: gcc-4.2    conftest.c  >&5
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
configure:3467: $? = 1
configure:3505: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3510: error: in `/Users/disaacs/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392':
configure:3512: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=gcc-4.2
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
ac_cv_prog_CC=gcc-4.2
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='ruby'
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='gcc-4.2'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CFLAGS=''
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPOUTFILE=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='1'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='9'
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
PREP=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.9.3'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2013-02-22'
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUNRUBY=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='1'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin12.3.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin12.3.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin12.3.0'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: It may there is no ruby version available for your system. You can check available rubies by "rvm list known". As I know, rubies for Mac begin with "macruby-"

Comment: Also you can try `rvm get head` to update rvm first

Comment: Do you have XCode installed on your OS X? check my answer below

Comment: Yes, I already have XCode installed on my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please first check if you have XCode installed on your Mac OS X

Make sure you are connected to the network.

Go to the Apple app store and download XCode first (it's free). 
See also: [How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4) , and http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1289543

Then try to install Ruby:

```
   rvm list known
   rvm requirements    # you might not have Xcode installed on your OS X

   rvm install 1.9.3
```

please check the instructions here:

https://rvm.io/rubies/installing/

if this does not work for you, try to upgrade RVM:

https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading/

Comment: what is the output of  `rvm info` ?

Comment: OK back at my computer... Running rvm requirements seems to have helped: it installed apple-gcc42. This is peculiar since I thought installing XCode would have done this.

Comment: But now there is a new problem: Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-dir=/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libyaml:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/readline:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libxml2:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libxslt:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/libksba:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/openssl:/Users/disaacs/.rvm/opt/sqlite --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',

Comment: OK figured it out! I had installed XCode, but I had not set up the command line tools (XCode > Preferences > Downloads). Thanks for your help!