# ./configure command not found, pkg-config

Tags: macos, pkg-config

When trying to install pkg-config on a brand new install of 10.8.5 i got a ./configure: no such file or directory.

first I downloaded the source with git

`git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/pkg-config`

then I switched to the directory

```
cd /Users/nah/Desktop/pkg-config
```

when I run ls I can see the configure file but when I run

```
./configure --with-internal-glib
```

I get ./configure: no such file or directory. Even though I see the file in the pkg-config directory.
When I searched for answers online The two i saw were are you in the correct directory which i clearly am, and the second answer i saw was to use homebrew or Macports. I know homebrew and macports will work but that doesn't really answer the question it's sort of a work around. I than realized that the configure file wasn't executable so I ran chmod on it to make it executable but I get the same thing. The other thing I thought of was the configure file is configure.ac , a quick glance at a bunch of other source files on my computer and they all have configure files with no .ac.
I also tried dragging the executable configure file to terminal to run it and I got
 line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `[2.62}`
 /Users/nah/pkg-config/configure.ac: line 1: 'AC_PREREQ([2.62])'
do you think there's a problem with the configure script for Mountain lion, i did this on snow leopard about a month ago with no problems.

so in conclusion, i can't install pkg-config using normal ./configure; make; make install;
And would like to know way to solve problem with out homebrew or Macports work around.

Comment: Just curious -- Did you remember to install Xcode before trying to compile software? Also -- It looks like Apple fails to add the command line tools to the PATH during the install. Check this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4

Comment: Run autogen.sh first.

Comment: when i ran autogen.sh it said autogen.sh: command not found. So i draged autogen.sh to the terminal and it said line 12: autoreconf: command not found

Comment: yea i did, i also installed the command line tools too.

Comment: You need to install m4 tools or how they are called on your system.

Comment: sorry, for the late late reply but installing m4 tools did the trick, thought i should reply to help anyone reading this i didn't expect so many views.

Comment: What is M4 tools and how do you install it?