# npm install xml2json fail to install

Tags: macos, node.js

I am trying to work on PUSh notifications for Android/ios using node.js. 
I am getting the below error when I try to install xml2json.
 Please help me to fix it

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/bertils/node_modules/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-expat@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "xml2json"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/bertils
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bertils/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `make` tool is not available on your system.

To fix this, you have 2 options:

- If you have `Xcode` already installed:

Go to `Xcode > Preferences > Downloads` and install the component named "Command Line Tools". All the relevant tools will be placed in `/usr/bin`.

- Alternative:

Go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads, sign in with your developer Apple ID and search for "Command Line Tools", then download and install the appropriate file.

Comment: Thank you after installing the command line tools, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue on linux rhel 7, see if it works for you too, what I found out was that I needed to install gcc libraries on my instance, so I went ahead and removed my node_modules folder and then ran the `sudo yum group install "Development Tools"`, in your case you might want to find the brew equivalent `sudo yum group install "Development Tools"` or `xcode-select --install`, and I then ran the npm install again and it worked!

Hope this helps, for issues related to installing gcc libraries and Development tools, one can refer to this url also: [Install gcc and dev tools](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-7-redhat-linux-install-gcc-compiler-development-tools/) or [Mac OS install dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4)