# Ruby Rails - issue with gcc on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, gcc, osx-mavericks

I am trying to create my first application on ruby rails.

- I am on Mac OsX (Mavericks)
- I have the latest xCode installed (5 i believe) + [command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#)
- I have installed the bitnami bundle [ruby stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/ruby)
- I have added rails (sudo gem install rails -V)

All steps until creating my own project work ---- [see here](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_RubyStack#What_is_the_default_installation_directory.3f)

In the ruby console I type:

```
sudo rails new helloworld
```

.. then it does some creational stuff till it hits the following lines:

```
run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.1) 
Using i18n (0.6.9) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.4) 
Using atomic (1.1.14) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using activesupport (4.0.2) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.2) 
Using mime-types (1.25.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.2) 
Using activemodel (4.0.2) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.1) 
Using activerecord (4.0.2) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.2) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.3) 
Using jquery-rails (3.1.0) 
Installing json (1.8.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
sh: line 1: 58350 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find gcc 2> /dev/null
gcc: error: unable to find utility "gcc", not a developer tool or in PATH
make: *** [generator.o] Error 72


Gem files will remain installed in /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Installing json-1.8.1 within rubyconsole doesn't work - I get the following error:

```
sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'

bash-3.2$ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
sh: line 1: 60535 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find gcc 2> /dev/null
gcc: error: unable to find utility "gcc", not a developer tool or in PATH
make: *** [generator.o] Error 72


Gem files will remain installed in /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Outside rubyconsole it works. However, that does not solve the issue above.

I followed these steps:

[How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4)

I also followed the steps here:

http://new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2013/10/24/3-quick-tips-for-coding-with-os-x-10-9-mavericks

Any help would be much appreciated .. Thanks, George

UPDATE: I run the following:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo mv gcc gcc_mavs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 gcc
```

Now I get a different error message:

```
Installing json (1.8.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
sh: line 1: 67709 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find as 2> /dev/null
as: error: unable to find utility "as", not a developer tool or in PATH
make: *** [generator.o] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Applications/rubystack-1.9.3-19/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, completely removed xcode & developer tools.

Reinstalled xocode 5.02 & developer tools for maverick (late october)

run the following command:

```sh
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Sovled.

Comment: This solution also works for those trying to pip install pycryptodome on MaxOSX