# bundle install does not complete execution. It gets stuck in the middle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

When I ran bundle install, it gets stuck towards the end.

Here's my bundle console output

```
 !  ~/r/mangoweb   master  bundle install                                                                           Sun Jul 27 12:45:28 IST 2014
Updating git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git
Updating git://github.com/Rameshv/mongoid-paranoia.git
Updating git://github.com/resque/resque.git
Updating git://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer.git
Updating git://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print.git
Updating https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby
Updating git://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost.git
Updating git@github.com:capistrano/rvm.git
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 0.3.40
Using activesupport 4.0.2
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.2
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.2
Using activemodel 4.0.2
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.2
Using addressable 2.3.6
Using awesome_print 1.2.0 from git://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print.git (at v2)
Using json 1.8.1
Using mini_portile 0.6.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.3.1
Using aws-sdk 1.49.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using better_errors 1.1.0
Using bson 2.3.0
Using bundler 1.6.1
Using colorize 0.7.3
Using net-ssh 2.9.1
Using net-scp 1.2.1
Using sshkit 1.5.1
Using capistrano 3.0.1
Using capistrano-bundler 1.1.2
Using capistrano-rails 1.1.0
Using capistrano-rvm 0.1.1 from git@github.com:capistrano/rvm.git (at master)
Using carrierwave 0.10.0
Using connection_pool 2.0.0
Using optionable 0.2.0
Using moped 2.0.0
Using origin 1.1.0
Using mongoid 4.0.0.alpha1 from git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git (at v4.0.0.alpha1)
Using mongoid-grid_fs 2.1.0
Using carrierwave-mongoid 0.7.1
Using timers 1.1.0
Using celluloid 0.15.2
Using choice 0.1.6
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.1
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.0.2
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
Using rails 4.0.2
Using commands 0.2.1
Using css_parser 1.3.5
Using daemon_controller 1.2.0
Using daemons 1.1.9
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.1.0
Using ejs 1.1.1
Using eventmachine 1.0.3
Using http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Using em-websocket 0.5.1
Using excon 0.38.0
Using factory_girl 4.4.0
Using faker 1.4.2
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using faraday 0.9.0
Using ffi 1.9.3
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using fog-core 1.23.0
Using fog-json 1.0.0
Using inflecto 0.0.2
Using fog-brightbox 0.1.1
Using fog-softlayer 0.3.11
Using ipaddress 0.8.0
Using fog 1.23.0
Using font-awesome-rails 4.1.0.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.4
Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
Using listen 2.7.9
Using lumberjack 1.0.9
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Using pry 0.10.0
Using guard 2.6.1
Using guard-livereload 2.3.0
Using haml 4.0.5
Using hashie 3.2.0
Using hirb 0.7.2
Using hpricot 0.8.6
Using htmlentities 4.3.2
Using jbuilder 1.5.3
Using jquery-rails 3.1.1
Using jwt 1.0.0
Using kaminari 0.16.1
Using launchy 2.4.2
Using letter_opener 1.2.0
```

I let it run for more than 30 minutes, but it still didn't get out of the loop. When I forced killed this process, I got an error saying that libv8 is not installed. I tried running this manually, but that didn't work either.

```
SystemExit: exit
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I assumed that my settings are corrupt, and did rvm implode and tried setting up everything from scratch, but I was stuck with the same issue.  I also ran a gem update --system just to check if everything upto date. Even that didn't help.

Here are some details,

Bundle version : 1.6.`
Ruby ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

Not sure what is the issue. Am I missing something here?

**Edit 1**

This is the error I'm getting while installing libv8gem

```
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
Compiling v8 for x64
Using python 2.7.5
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
Using compiler: g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
../src/cached-powers.cc:136:18: error: unused variable 'kCachedPowersLength' [-Werror,-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int kCachedPowersLength = ARRAY_SIZE(kCachedPowers);
                 ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o] Error 1
make: *** [x64.release] Error 2
/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:36:in `block in verify_installation!': libv8 did not install properly, expected binary v8 archive '/Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a'to exist, but it was not found (Libv8::Location::Vendor::ArchiveNotFound)
    from /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:35:in `verify_installation!'
    from /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:26:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
GYP_GENERATORS=make \
    build/gyp/gyp --generator-output="out" build/all.gyp \
                  -Ibuild/standalone.gypi --depth=. \
                  -Dv8_target_arch=x64 \
                  -S.x64  -Dv8_enable_backtrace=1 -Dv8_can_use_vfp2_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv2 -Dv8_can_use_vfp3_instructions=true -Darm_fpu=vfpv3
  CXX(target) /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/allocation.o
  CXX(target) /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.o
  CXX(target) /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum.o
  CXX(target) /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/bignum-dtoa.o
  CXX(target) /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/preparser_lib/src/cached-powers.o

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/skmvasu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/libv8-3.16.14.3/gem_make.out
```

**Edit 2**

I finally found the problem. My system updated to the latest version of Mavericks 10.9.4. There is some issue with a mac update and libv8 gem, that I don't fully understand, but I guess it has something to do with the old ruby setup. So, did an rvm implode and then installed it from scratch, and also reinstalled ruby. After that everything worked like a charm. If anyone is facing the same issue take a look at this thread https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/120. This might help shed some light to this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your 'constructive' advice. But this used to work till yesterday, and nothing has changed drastically since then. Plus I went through a similar issue at https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/120 and tried everything listed there, before posting here.

Comment: what version of __xcode__ you are using?

Comment: I'm running Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)

Comment: I also met the same issue. However running `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` as instructed actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

libv8 is a C-binded lib, it's not a RVM issue, it's almost certainly a dependency issue in your system. Try googling for "install libv8 under macos" or try one of the alternative JS interpreters as explained on https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs (you should actually have this link in Gemfile by default)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. This setup was working till yesterday. My Mac updated to 10.9.4 sometime back. I guess that's screwing this up. Let me check that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is referencing a missing GCC compiler. It looks like you might be running OS X and Xcode. According to this answer [How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4) you may have to tell Xcopy specifically that you want the command line tools installed.

Ultimately just go to the "Preferences" menu in Xcode, choose "Downloads", and then select "Command Line Tools" from the list to install them.