# Error installing Ruby 1.9.2 on Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-yosemite

I'm getting an error when installing ruby 1.9.2 with rvm on Yosemite. Could someone help me? I updated homebrew and rvm. I'm working with someone else on this project so I can't upgrade ruby. I put a link to my output below. Thanks ahead of time!

```
Kanyons-MacBook-Pro:~ USERNAME$ rvm install 1.9.2-head
ruby-1.9.2-head - #removing src/ruby-1.9.2-head..
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
HEAD is now at 5d9f08f bump patchlevel
From git://github.com/ruby/ruby
 * branch            ruby_1_9_2 -> FETCH_HEAD
Current branch ruby_1_9_2 is up to date.
Copying from repo to src path...
ruby-1.9.2-head - #applying patch /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.2/head/r42282.patch.
ruby-1.9.2-head - #applying patch /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/patches/ruby/ssl_no_ec2m.patch.
ruby-1.9.2-head - #autoreconf.
ruby-1.9.2-head - #configuring..........................................
ruby-1.9.2-head - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.9.2-head - #compiling..................
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/USERNAME/.rvm/log/1413513694_ruby-1.9.2-head/make.log
generating newline.c ...
converter for universal_newline
converter for crlf_newline
converter for cr_newline
done.  (0.06user 0.00system 0.01elapsed)
/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2 -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I.        -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o newline.o -c newline.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2 -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin14.0.0 -I./include -I. -DRUBY_EXPORT -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -o dmyext.o -c dmyext.c
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2 -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -fno-common -pipe -L. -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib         -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend   main.o dmydln.o dmyencoding.o dmyversion.o miniprelude.o array.o bignum.o class.o compar.o complex.o dir.o dln_find.o enum.o enumerator.o error.o eval.o load.o proc.o file.o gc.o hash.o inits.o io.o marshal.o math.o node.o numeric.o object.o pack.o parse.o process.o random.o range.o rational.o re.o regcomp.o regenc.o regerror.o regexec.o regparse.o regsyntax.o ruby.o safe.o signal.o sprintf.o st.o strftime.o string.o struct.o time.o transcode.o util.o variable.o compile.o debug.o iseq.o vm.o vm_dump.o thread.o cont.o ascii.o us_ascii.o unicode.o utf_8.o newline.o  dmyext.o -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  -o miniruby
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
miniruby(65084,0x7fff7bed0300) malloc: *** error for object 0x100801a08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who is trying to install ruby 1.9.2 on Yosemite, there is no fix. I installed 1.9.3 and it works great.

For more information on why 1.9.2 won't compile correctly, use the bug reports on Github below.

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3096#issuecomment-59797969
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3099#issuecomment-60187208

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the best answer, but it seems like it's a bug in the way OSX handles GCC... or something. I've found a thread that mentions a patch and also how to install it here:  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61407

I haven't done it yet, but I'm about to and I'll report back. Not sure if that's an "answer" persay, but this is my problem as well and I need to get this fixed pronto!

EDIT: None of the patches worked (probably because I didn't know how to install them, but running this line in my terminal, then doing `rvm install 1.9.2` seemed to work:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Taken from this answer: [How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4)

Comment: Both ideas did not work for me for some reason. I'm going to uninstall everything and reinstall brew and rvm and see if that fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: Did that work for you? I ended up having to revert to a time machine backup to get my environment to work with 1.9.2

Comment: It did not. I think it's the compiler is not working with Yosemite.

Comment: We couldn't get it to work with 1.9.2 and struggled with 1.9.x at all.

Comment: I built 1.9.2-p320 but it crashes with a malloc error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried RBENV instead?

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

If you ever have issues installing things on your native system you could
always try building a VM using Vagrant, also good for deployment.

I used it for a client who has older ROR app. Makes sharing dev environments dead easy.

https://www.vagrantup.com/