# GCC Segmentation Fault Mac

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

I have been having some trouble getting my gcc and g++ compiler to work on my
mac (OSX Yosemite 10.10.2).

I have written up a simple "Hello World" program and even these seem to not
work. The two program that I tried to run are

**hello.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**hello.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}
```

I can compile the C program using `cc hello.c` and everything works fine, but
when I do `gcc hello.c` I get this error

```
[1]    38508 segmentation fault  gcc hello.c
```

I get a similar error attempting to compile my C++ code

```
[1]    38596 segmentation fault  g++ hello.cpp
```

I did `which gcc` and I get `/opt/local/bin/gcc` and that directory is in my
path.
( `/usr/texbin /opt/local/bin /opt/local/sbin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin/usr/bin` )

So I am confused as to what is happening. I thought I downloaded all of the
Xcode things that I needed. I would like to get `gcc` and `g++` running
properly. I hope that you can help.

Thanks!

Comment: if on OS X, why don't you use `clang`?

Comment: the output of `gcc -v` might help, but I'm afraid you will get segfault with this command as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that gcc and g++ have to be installed/added to the MAC os.

From your description, I would expect that the wrong version of those tools was installed.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/) should help.

Be sure to read all the answers to the question before proceeding with a gcc installation.

Comment: I used the PATH manipulation they suggested and it seems to have fixed my problem. export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem where even `gcc --version`was giving me a "Segmentation fault: 11". This is on OSX 10.10.5 with XCode 6.4. After much googling and no solution, I found that clang (Apple's LLVM-based C compiler) is intended to be a compatible replacement for gcc, so I just sym-linked gcc to clang as follows:

```
whence gcc #=> /usr/local/bin/gcc
whence clang #=> /usr/bin/clang
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo mv gcc gcc_OLD
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang /usr/local/bin/gcc
gcc -v
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Now I am able to successfully compile c-language stuff, like my ruby extensions.