# Helo with visual studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

could someone help with how can I create a new project on a mac, like in windows when I'm opening win32 console app to start writing C programing?

Comment: how are android, ios, arrays relevant to this?

Comment: What are you asking? Why "visual studio"? Are you looking for software recommendations (like a C compiler and/or IDE for MacOS)? If so, this is off-topic here.

Comment: Have you installed Visual Studio on iOS?

Comment: @N.Ivanov: the Android SDK is bundled with Visual Studio on iOS.

Comment: @cdarke but that is not relevant to his question at all. There is no `C` programming in Android. Also he is asking how to set it on a Mac, not an iPhone, that's why I raised the issue with wrong tags. Thanks!

Comment: @N.Ivanov:  well there is the NDK on Android for C and C++ development, although I agree that most development is in Java.  Point is that VS on Mac is based on the Xamarin product and is used for cross-platform development, mostly based around .Net (including C#).  However I agree that the tags were not relevant to this question, so yes, you are right about that.

Comment: First of all thank you everybody for your answers. I've already installed visual studio on my mac, since this is the software we are using at school. But I don't know how to open a new project like we do at class

Answer (score 0):

You can use emacs or xcode on the OSX 
with emacs create a project in c and use gcc

Comment: Visual Studio is available for Apple Mac (but personally I use vi)

Comment: of course but maybe he was using notepad on windows and he don't know Visual Studio

Comment: First of all thank you everybody for your answers. I've already installed visual studio on my mac, since this is the software we are using at school. But I don't know how to open a new project like we do at class

Answer (score 0):

You can't do C development using Visual Studio for Mac.  The product is the Xamarin toolset used for .Net cross-platform development only.

Users have requested that C and C++ is added [(vote here)](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17141708-support-c-in-visual-studio-for-mac), so it is possible that it could be added in the future.

Meanwhile, see [How to use/install gcc on Mac OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4)

Comment: First of all thank you everybody for your answers. I've already installed visual studio on my mac, since this is the software we are using at school. But I don't know how to open a new project like we do at class

Comment: @user8898941:  are you learning C?  Is your class using Windows?  If the answer is "yes" to those questions, then read my answer.  Visual Studio on Mac cannot be used for C, but there are other products available.  Note that "projects" are only required if you are using an integrated Development Environment like Visual Studio or Xcode, they have nothing to do with C.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend